# Converting RTF to Word using command line tools

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

Does Microsoft provide any tools for converting different file formats that Microsoft Word supports? I'd like to convert RTF to MS Word format using command line tools in Mac OS X. I have MS Word for Mac 2011 (14.1.2). If not, is there an open source alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/ claims that it is capable, but it doesn't work smoothly yet.

Comment: It's not command-line (and it's kinda slow), but you can do a batch convert via Word by going to the scroll menu (in the menu bar)->Sample Automator Workflows->Convert the format of specified Word files.

Comment: I found this question useful and wanted to up-vote, only to find that it's my own question. Hahaha